# How much gas is needed to produce absorption lines?

Tags: experimental-physics, scattering-cross-section, absorption

I am trying to know whether it would be possible to do an undergraduate laboratory experiment to measure absorption lines produced by a gas. The idea is to have a background source of light with a continuous spectrum (either sunlight or an incandescent light bulb), a [spectrometer](https://www.oceaninsight.com/products/spectrometers/general-purpose-spectrometer/ocean-sr2-series-spectrometers/ocean-sr2-vis-nir-spectrometers/), and some gas in between. I thought helium would be best, because it's easy to obtain, seems safe, and the amount of spectral lines is small (but I'm open to suggestions).

I imagine the attenuation in the intensity would be related to the optical depth ($\tau$), which in turn would be related to the absorption cross section ($\sigma$) and number density ($n$) of the gas. That is, the intensity after absorption ($I$) would be related to that before absorption ($I_0$) as
$$I(\lambda)=I_0(\lambda)e^{-\tau(\lambda)},$$
where $\tau$ is something like
$$\tau(\lambda)=\int_0^L n(\mathbf x) \left<\sigma(\lambda)\right>\,\mathrm dx.
$$

If the gas is uniformly distributed in a container, $\tau(\lambda)=n L \left<\sigma(\lambda)\right>$, where $L$ is the length along the line of sight.

If the gas can be taken as ideal, I can relate $n$ to $p$ (pressure) easily. This would allow me to estimate a pressure threshold $p_\mathrm{th}$ that would produce enough attenuation to be detectable. This could be done by imposing an optical depth threshold around the central position of an absorption line, or a threshold on the integrated optical depth around it. Either way, it would be something like
$$p>p_\mathrm{th}\sim\frac{\tau_\mathrm{th} kT}{L\left<\sigma\right>.}$$

So, my question is either of the following:

- where could I find data for $\left<\sigma\right>$ to figure this out on my own?, or
- does anyone with expertise know if this is feasible at all?

Comment: You have a problem in that if you increase the pressure, the line will be broadened. Much will depend on what spectral resolution you are aiming for. Weak lines can be seen better at higher resolution.

Comment: Is that because an increase of $p$ produces an increase in $T$ which produces an increase in the dispersion of the velocity distribution of the atoms in the gas?
I just checked and the nominal resolution of our spectrometers is $1.34\,\mathrm{nm}$.

Comment: Pressure broadening. Compare low pressure and high pressure sodium lamps.